# Why is half of the house without power with no visible blown fuses?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

So I had a small gathering last night at a house that wasn't mine, and someone decided it would be a great idea to plug two space heaters into the same outlet.... the power not only went out in that room, but also in the entire downstairs area and the garage. However, I know very little about fuses and all that stuff so I am at a standstill on what to do.  I went down to the fuse box, but the entire thing was switched off. I turned it on and held the reset button down and it made a noise, but the power didn't return. The fuse box is obviously very old and it says "class 2 transformer and 7870 lighting". I can't call an electrician because it's not my house and I honestly don't have the money.

What to do?

Comment: Is the homeowner telling you to fix it? :P I'd let them call the electrician in if I was in your shoes...

Comment: Fuses don't turn on and off. I can't understand why "class 2 transformer and 7870 lighting" would be written on either a fuse box or a breaker panel and suspect you're looking at something completely different. Electricity is very dangerous and you obviously have no idea what you're doing at the most basic level. I don't think this is a problem that you should attempt to fix yourself due to safety concerns.

Comment: Could you take a photo of the panel, I was called in on a similar problem on a FPE panel that a main section breaker did not trip and the overload melted the stabs at the back of the breaker feeding the small section for lighting and outlets. The sound it made was like arc welding but not as loud no smoke at that point. The panel had to be replaced. Since that panel I have worked on 3 others only 1 of the 4 was fully functional. This needs to be fully checked out no matter what brand of panel before a full blown fire results.

Comment: There might be more than one panel.